# Set custom referrer in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

According to the official doc

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

> The code should be added near the top of the  tag and before any
>   other script or CSS tags

So, after the call of `ga('send', 'pageview');`, and later in my page, I've invoked the call to alter the referrer, such as

```
ga('set', 'referrer', 'xxx');
```

Will it be used? If not, what are the proper way to ater the referrer afterward?

Answer (score 0):

It will be used by calls that are made after the set call (if any). It will not be used for the pageview call, since the pageview call is already processed by the time the set is executed. You cannot apply a set call to preceding hits. If you want to apply the custom referrer to your pageview call you need to include it between the "create" call and the pageview.